# Pivot table pandas with column prefix

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to reshape dataframe as shown in the images. I want to create a wide dataframe  with the values in asset as new columns with the prefix asset_. In the new asset_ columns the corresponding value from the value column should be stored. See attached images. This is some sort of pivot operation but I can't figure out following:

1. How to dynamically add the prefix asset_ to the new columns.
2. How to keep the ser_num and day column that have the same values for each row.

I tried to do this with pandas.pivot but there are no prefix parameter and I do not want to create any multilevel indexes:

```
Import pandas as pd
data  = {"rowkey":["2017:P7W", "2017:P7W", "2017:P7W"], 
            "ser_num":[467, 467, 467], 
            "asset": ["A", "B", "C"], 
            "value": [123,456, 789],
           "day":[1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.pivot(index="rowkey", columns="asset", values="value").reset_index()
```

In my problem I have 200+ unique assets so the result will be a very wide dataframe. See images:

[Dataframe before manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0StRE.png)

[Dataframe after manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08wSV.png)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `add_prefix()` method as shown below:

```py
# Create pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd 
data  = {
  "rowkey": ["2017:P7W", "2017:P7W", "2017:P7W"], 
  "ser_num": [467, 467, 467], "asset": ["A", "B", "C"], 
  "value": [123,456,789],"day":[1,1,1]
} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pivot data and add prefix
df.pivot(index="rowkey",columns="asset",values="value").reset_index().add_prefix('asset_')
```

here an output after manipulation:

[image: output]

Best,

Abakar

Comment: This is a great answer, only a small adjustment that the function is `add_prefix()` with two d's

Comment: I fixed now the missing d. Thanks @HaplessEcologist

Comment: Here we prefix also rowkey, which is not ideal I think :) For those looking how to change that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311932/how-to-add-prefix-to-column-names-except-some-columns