# How to add prefix to column names except some columns?

Tags: python, pandas

This is an adaptation of a question posed by @ScalaBoy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380310/how-to-add-suffix-to-column-names-except-some-columns)  and answered by @timgeb, the question is the same, except it is about a prefix not suffix:

Given pandas DataFrame, how can I add the prefix "new_" to all columns except two columns Id and Name?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,'Alex',22,'single'],[2,'Bob',32,'married'],[3,'Clarke',23,'single']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id','Name','Age','Status'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use list comprehension on the dataframe column header object, this way you aren't manipulating nor copying the entire dataframe:

```
df.columns = [f'new_{i}' if i not in ['Name', 'Id'] else f'{i}' for i in df.columns]

df
```

Output:

```
   Id    Name  new_Age new_Status
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```

Comment: This works perfectly, a great solution so I didn't need to copy the data frame! Can I ask for a little more clarification of how the "[f'new_{i}' if i not in ['Name', 'Id'] else f'{i}' for i in df.columns]
" works? I'm v new to python, and understanding what this section means would help me in future :)

Comment: Yes, this is using [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) with [f-string formatting](https://zetcode.com/python/fstring/) and a [ternary operation](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators).

Answer (score 7):

Use add_prefix. This function is applied to the whole dataframe. To hide columns you dont need renamed, set them as index. After renaming you can reset back the index. Code below

```
df=df.set_index(['Id', 'Name']).add_prefix('new_').reset_index()



    Id    Name  new_Age new_Status
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rename` method:

```
df.rename({col:'new_'+ col for col in df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['Id','Name'])]}, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
df.rename(columns = lambda col: f"new_{col}" 
                                if col not in ('Name', 'Id') 
                                else col
          )

   Id    Name  new_Age new_Status
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```

You could achieve it with regex; however, in my opinion, it is not as clear as the previous solution:

```py
new_col = df.columns.str.replace(pat = r"\b(?!Id|Name\b).+", 
                                 repl = lambda m: f"new_{m[0]}", 
                                 regex=True)

df.set_axis(new_col, axis=1) # or df.columns = new_col

   Id    Name  new_Age new_Status
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```